# trying to Join 2 table query in Fluent laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Im trying to Joing 2 table in Fluent trough my Model i run the query on mysql client and give me the return i want.

this is the standard query

```
select `songlist`.*, `queuelist`.* from `songlist` inner join `queuelist` on `songlist`.`id` = `queuelist`.`songID` where `queuelist`.`songID` = songlist.ID and `songlist`.`songtype` = 'S' and `songlist`.`artist` <> "" order by `queuelist`.`sortID` ASC limit 4
```

it does return the data im looking for.

now on my model using fluent.

i did like this.

```
public static function comingUp()
{

    $getcomingUp = DB::table('songlist')
    ->join('queuelist', 'songlist.id', '=', 'queuelist.songID')
    ->select('songlist.*','queuelist.*')

    ->where('queuelist.songID', '=', 'songlist.ID')
    ->where('songlist.songtype', '=', 'S')
    ->where('songlist.artist', '<>', '')        
    ->orderBy('queuelist.sortID', 'ASC')
    ->take('4')
    ->get();

    return $getcomingUp;



}
```

and my controller to test if i get the data look like this

```
public function getComingUp()
{
    $getcomingUp = Radio::comingUp();

foreach ($getcomingUp as $cup)
 {
echo $cup->title;
 }


 // return View::make('comingup', compact('comingup'));


}
```

as you can see the foreach is no returning any data there is nothing wrong with the query because laravel give me no error at all. but i cant just get the foreach to display the data im looking for.

i try with $cup->songlist.title;
and it dont work ether.

Thanks any help will be appretiated. againg sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
public static function comingUp()
{

    $getcomingUp = DB::table('songlist')
      ->select('songlist.*','queuelist.*')
    ->join('queuelist', 'queuelist.songID', '=', 'songlist.id')



    ->where('songlist.songtype', '=', 'S')
    ->where('songlist.artist', '<>', '')        
    ->orderBy('queuelist.sortID', 'ASC')
    ->take('4')
    ->get();

    return $getcomingUp;



}
```

Comment: Omg i had the ->select in the wrong place silly me i would have nerver find it. :(  Thanks alot.